# DiscordJS role set returns API Error: Missing Permissions

Tags: discord

I try to set the member roles, but it doesn't set the permissions.

My index.js file:

```
    var u, s, m;

    await bot.users.fetch(message.author.id)
                        .then(user => { u = user; });
    await bot.guilds.fetch('419248578121433100')
                        .then(guild => { s = guild; });
    await s.members.fetch(u)
                        .then(member => { m = member; });

    axios.get('/process')
    .then(function (response)
    {
        var dptos = response.data.dptos;
        var attrs = response.data.userAttrs;
        var roles = response.data.roles;

        if(dptos.length > 0) m.setNickname(dptos[0].position + ' | ' + attrs.name + ' ' + attrs.surname);
        else m.setNickname(attrs.name + ' ' + attrs.surname + ' | ' + '123456');

        m.roles.set(roles)
        .then(function(member)
        {
            let fd = fs.openSync('log.txt', 'w');
            fs.writeSync(fd, JSON.stringify(member.roles.cache));
            fs.closeSync(fd);

        })
        .catch(function(error)
        {
            let fd = fs.openSync('error.txt', 'w');
            fs.writeSync(fd, error);
            fs.closeSync(fd);

        });

        return message.reply('Congrats!'); 
    })
    .catch(function (error)
    {
        return message.reply('error!'); 
    });
}
```

The axios request works as expected and the data is obtained correctly.

Screenshots:

[Bot position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pZgy.png)

[Bot general permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X07xB.png)

**UPDATE 1**: [Nickname permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGB9a.png)

What could be the issue?

Comment: Could you provide the response status code?

Comment: If you are trying to edit a user with the "discord admin" role, then it's because the bots position isn't #1.

Comment: No, I'm not. The user I'm trying to give the role has no roles at all

Comment: status code is 200

Comment: Are you sure the missing perm is adding roles? This code also requires perms to set nicknames.

Comment: I have added UPDATE 1 with the screenshot for nickname permissions. I have set all permissions to ON, but still no luck. I'm getting mad haha.

Comment: I found the solution:
The issue was that it's fetching the message author's id. That's actually ME testing. I'm the server's owner, so that's why it wasn't doing anything. Hope this can help someone else.